# What are these concrete posts near the Gallow Hill water tower in Dundee, Scotland?

Tags: scotland, manmade-object-identification

I've been walking my dog recently in the Templeton woods in Dundee, Scotland. When I walked past the Gallow Hill water tower I came across these concrete (?) posts. There were about 20-30 of them and I'd like to know if anyone can tell me what these are and why they're there?

[image]

This is where the water tower is, but I can't see the posts on the satellite image:

[56°29'43.3"N 3°02'02.6"W (Google Maps)](https://goo.gl/maps/4nFet5Ezt9x)

Comment: Structure of a building at some time?  They could not get a cement truck in so they buried posts.

Comment: That's an old building foundation.

Comment: Neither the layout nor the structure is a common type of building foundation. The lack of obvious other debris is also odd. This must have been an unusual structure

Comment: [Old OS maps](http://maps.nls.uk/geo/explore/#zoom=16&lat=56.4955&lon=-3.0346&layers=10&b=1) show some additional buildings without saying what they are.  Are they in the right place (a few tens of metres east of the tower)?

Comment: @ChrisH They indeed match the location! Can't say which one of the two it is though. Unfortunate, that it doesn't say what they were.

Comment: They appear at the same time as the tower according to the maps.

Comment: @ChrisH Well that's good to know though. I assume those will have been foundation posts as mentioned before then?

Comment: Can you add a precise location (grid reference or WGS84 coordinates)?  The photo doesn't seem to have any EXIF tags.

Comment: @TobySpeight Does this help? http://www.nearby.org.uk/coord.cgi?p=56.495325%2C+-3.033365

Comment: Thanks, @Baz.  I was hoping that the NLS might have 6-inch or 25-inch maps, but the tower isn't on maps before the late 1940s or early 1950s.  There's a early-1960's [2½-inch](http://maps.nls.uk/geo/explore/#zoom=19&lat=56.4951&lon=-3.0333&layers=10&b=4) (Javascript required) showing the tower and buildings, but the other maps are either too early or too small scale.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They appear to be part of a water tank.

I've found a [1954 OS map that describes buildings at that location as "tanks"](https://www.old-maps.co.uk/#/Map/336500/732500/12/100954) -- a term also applied on the same map to the water tower itself.  Earlier maps don't show them

The [current OS map](http://www.streetmap.co.uk/map.srf?x=340385&y=730678&z=120&sv=dundee&st=3&tl=Map+of+Dundee,+Dundee+City+[City/Town/Village]&searchp=ids.srf&mapp=map.srf) only shows the tower itself.

Without a scale so making very rough guesses as to the diameter of the silver birch trees, they've been there a decade or so according to [this paper](http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/yadda/element/bwmeta1.element.agro-9e85fb25-bae7-4ba3-a446-d051ce98ca2c/c/tkaczyk13-4-8-e.pdf) (which was looking at rather different terrain so we can only guess very roughly).  Of course the trees may have been planted long after the structure was demolished.

Indeed [this map from 1989](https://www.old-maps.co.uk/#/Map/336500/732500/10/101322) doesn't show anything except the main water tower (though something is present in 1979).

And that's as much as I can tell -- google has no archive news about Gallow Hill or Clatoo long enough ago to be relevant, and I can't find photos other than modern ones.

Comment: Those trees don't look "planted" to me - more likely to be natural colonisation.

Answer (score 12):

There were two large steel water tanks on these foundations back in the 1960's.
The tanks were rectangular. I used to play in these woods as a child and remember the tanks as being very rusty and military looking.