# What is this abandoned equipment and shed on skids near Mono Lake CA?

Tags: california, history, manmade-object-identification

I found this abandoned building with what looked like some sort of radio gear while hiking near Mono Lake  California.

The shed on skids

[image]

[image]

Close up of inside
[image]

Does anyone know what this was originally used for?

Comment: Not confident this is on topic for TGO.

Comment: @studiohack This is https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/what-are-these-concrete-posts-near-the-gallow-hill-water-tower-in-dundee-scotla

Comment: I suspect the dish was on the tower. With a dish antenna, it is unlikely to be a radio repeater. More likely transmitting data from the location to somewhere else. Could be weather, snow pack, or something else.

Comment: On second thought, the dish could have been a back-haul route to link a repeater into a network, so it could have been an old repeater.

Comment: Likely a repeater, those are all over the place in remote areas for local park and gov. comms.

Answer (score 6):

This is likely a 1960s Mono County Television Corporation CATV (Community Access/Antenna Television) [broadcast translator/repeater station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_relay_station). The original CATV - a precursor to modern Cable TV systems - was common "[in areas where over-the-air TV reception was limited by distance from transmitters or mountainous terrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_television)". As this [former employee notes](https://www.linkedin.com/in/dan-roberts-aa553026/details/experience/), Mono County Television "installed and maintained Community and Cable Television Systems, and serviced many mountaintop Repeater Sites for Communication, Education and Entertainment throughout Mono and Northern Inyo Counties."

That this is a CATV station is consistent with the leftover equipment. In the bottom photo, you can see the old logos of Blonder-Tongue Laboratories (the "B" over a stylized "T", see [here](https://www.nmspacemuseum.org/object_collection/james-n-oleary/) for an example) and Benco Television Associates ("Benco" over a stylized atom, see [here](http://theoldcatvequipmentmuseum.org/160/162/1622/index.html#BencoTelevisionAssociatesAmplifiermodel_Senior_BB-500--1.JPG) for an example). They were both [big providers of CATV equipment](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aworldradiohistory.com+benco+blonder-tongue&client=firefox-b-d&ei=Ak6fY7m7Mf6SytMPyNWMmA8&ved=0ahUKEwi5xOng2IP8AhV-iXIEHcgqA_MQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=site%3Aworldradiohistory.com+benco+blonder-tongue&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQA0oECEEYAUoECEYYAFD6A1jaZWDFaGgCcAB4AIABUYgBrguSAQIyM5gBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)  in the era. Blonder-Tongue bought Benco in 1960 and sold it in 1965. [Blonder-Tongue Laboratories](https://www.blondertongue.com) still exists, but with a very different Logo, and Benco also had various logos over the years before it was sold again, merged, and eventually disappeared.